# Integrate $\int\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+2}} dx$ .

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, integral-transforms

Q)  $\int\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+2}} dx$ .

Tried rationalising the numerator twice to get Numerator =-2 but not able to simplify denominator

The question reduces to (as per my rationalising)

$$\int \frac{-2}{\bigl(x - \sqrt{x^2+2}\bigr)\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x^2+2}}}\,dx$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}dx\;$$

Now Put $$\displaystyle (x+\sqrt{x^2+2}) = e^{2t}\;$$ Then $$\displaystyle \left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}\right)dx = 2e^{2t}dt$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \left(\frac{e^{2t}}{\sqrt{x^2+2}}\right)dx = 2e^{2t}dt\Rightarrow dx = 2\sqrt{x^2+2}dt$$

Now Using $$\displaystyle \bullet\;  \left(\sqrt{x^2+2}+x\right)\cdot \left(\sqrt{x^2+2}-x\right) = 2$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \left(\sqrt{x^2+2}-x\right) = \frac{2}{e^{2t}}$$

Now $$\displaystyle \sqrt{x^2+2} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(e^{2t}+\frac{2}{e^{2t}}\right)$$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \int e^{t}\cdot \left(e^{2t}+\frac{2}{e^{2t}}\right)dt = \int e^{3t}dt+2\int e^{-t}dt$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{3}e^{3t}-2e^{-t}+\mathcal{C} = \frac{1}{3}\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}-2\cdot \left(x+\sqrt{x^2+2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: Finally the answer that i needed

Comment: Especially steps 4,5,6 are just gold , #respect

Comment: This time I'm a bit surprised about your choice of change of variables, but of course it also works! :)

Comment: I believe you have a missing factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in your answer (and in the expression for $\sqrt{x^2+2}$).

Comment: @user84413 yea some some small changes are there

Comment: How do you get to $\displaystyle (x+\sqrt{x^2+2}) = e^{2t}\;$ ?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**:

One could choose :

> $$t=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2+2}}$$ then square to get a more meaningful equation$$t^2-x=\sqrt{x^2+2}$$ squaring again and solving for $x$ we get $$x=\frac{t^4-2}{2t^2}$$

I'm sure you can take it from here. If not, prompt me for more details.

Comment: Thank You for your time and effort to answer my question

Comment: Now do we hve to put the value of x

Answer (score 5):

Try the substitution
$$
u=x+\sqrt{x^2+2}.
$$
After simplification, you will probably end up with
$$
\int \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{u}+\frac{1}{u\sqrt{u}}\,du
$$
which you probably can integrate directly(?).