# Evaluate $\int\sqrt {x+\sqrt{x^2 +2}} dx$

Tags: integration

I have solved this question, but there are two answers two this. The first, which I solved by substituting $\sqrt{x+\sqrt {x^2+2}} =t$ is $\frac 13 (x+\sqrt{x^2 +2})^{\frac 32} -2 (x+\sqrt{x^2+2})^{-\frac 12} +C$

The other form is $\frac 27 (x+\sqrt{x^2+2})^{\frac 72} -2(x+\sqrt{x^2+2}) +C$

I don’t how to interconvert these two answers. How do I obtain the second result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433771/integrate-int-sqrtx-sqrtx22-dx **or** https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484956/integral-int-sqrtx-sqrtx22dx

Comment: @0-thUserSumanta it doesn’t, since I have already solved it using the methods given there. However, I need the answer in a different form

Comment: The second result is actually incorrect, and one can check by differentiating it.